# Deck block on top of slab

Tags: concrete, shed, pier-blocks

I have a huge concrete retaining wall and patio in the back of my house. I want to build a small 8'x9' shed structure within the patio. I'm in the SF area - we get frost maybe once every 5 years. We get tons of rain (sometimes) and the patio is sloped so the rain water doesn't pool. I'd like to build the shed on concrete deck blocks so no wood or metal is exposed to the water and the bottom of the shed has enough clearance. Id like to use adjustable steel deck supports to level the shed over what is an intentionally sloped surface.

Is this a terrible idea?? Using deck blocks on top of the slab?

Comment: what are the concrete blocks on top of concrete deck for ?

Comment: not on top of a deck... it's a concrete patio outside the back of the house. it's surrounded by a 9' retaining wall.  I want to put it there because that's the space I have and the ideal distance from the house: within the patio.

Comment: we're on a downslope and this retaining wall stops erosion around the house. it spans the length of the house and encloses the patio. hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you, so what is going to hold the shed from flying away

Comment: For that small of a shed, should not have any problem with deck blocks.  Would use pressure treated wood.  Leave space between the shed and wall for air movement/maybe people movement.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Wondering if there is a better way to do this? Or if this makes enough sense?      Due to the structural nature of the retaining wall and patio and the erosion that takes place on this hill, I'm very hesitant to disturb the concrete slab by attempting to affix posts to it, hence my plan.